# onFling and onSCroll methods are not detecting on Android Canvas?

Tags: android, canvas, gesture

In my sample app, I'm drawing a view using a Canvas and GestureDetector. For the OnGestureListener, all methods are working except onFling and onScroll.

Can anybody sugest me how I can detect the Fling and Scroll gestures on the Canvas.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make sure your onDown method in your GestureListener class is returning true.  OnFling and OnScroll won't fire without the OnDown returning true.